# Will an Amazon EC2 Instance State-change Notification be triggered when an instance enters or leaves a provided state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

So if I have the following definition for a CloudWatch Event:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "pending"
    ]
  }
}
```

Will AWS trigger this event when an EC2 Instance enters the `pending` state, or when an EC2 Instance in the `pending` state changes to a different state?

I'm looking for an authoritative answer, as the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#ec2_event_type) is unclear as to which it is.

Comment: I still haven't found an answer to this, does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

AWS will trigger this event when an EC2 Instance enters the `pending` state.

Quote from AWS documentation:

> An instance enters the `pending` state when it launches for the first time, or when it is restarted after being in the stopped state.
>
> After the instance is ready for you, it enters the `running` state

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html#instance-launch