# Trigger script automatically on EC2 creation (no user data)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

Everytime an EC2 instance gets created, I want to run a script on that instance. I understand this could be done using the **user_data** parameter but some of these instances get created manually so people may forget to fill in that parameter sometimes. I want to rely on something automatic instead.

I figured to do it with *EventBridge*, catch an event that would indicate me that an instance has been created then trigger a *lambda* that would run the script. But when looking in the documentation I couldn't find any event that would relate to "EC2 created", see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/monitoring-instance-state-changes.html.

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: you could achieve this by running an SSM document every time an instance is registered.

Comment: @AnthonyB. Are you suggesting that there is a built-in way to trigger an SSM document every time an instance is created? Or should I go the path of EventBridge -> Lambda -> SSM (like provided in the answer below)

Comment: Yes, the path mentioned with EventBridge, Lambda and SSM is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an EventBridge rule with the following pattern to catch the event:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ec2"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["ec2.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["RunInstances"]
  }
}
```

and configure the target of the rule to be an AWS lambda function. Configure the lambda to parse the event and invoke an SSM run command against the instance.

Comment: How did you knew about the informations to fill in the `detail` section? I have trouble navigating the documentation and finding what events are being triggered after certain actions. For example those you gave are not provided  in the documentation I linked. Thanks btw.

Comment: @Mit94 if you inspect the cloudtrail logs you'll see the event that is generated when an instance in started

Comment: @Paolo - I was going through your answer, would you let me know that how do I fetch InstanceId with the help of boto3 from your eventbridge rule ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have an EventBridge Rule with the following detail:

```
{
  "detail-type": ["EC2 Instance State-change Notification"],
  "detail": {
    "state": ["running"]
  },
  "source": ["aws.ec2"]
}
```

And my target is a lambda function that runs an SSM document on that instance.

Comment: I just implemented this, however I noticed that most of the time, the lambda would be triggered before the SSM agent actually becomes active which leads to the failure of the SSM Command. I wonder if you faced the same issue? I created a new question for this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74448077/catch-event-when-an-ssm-agent-becomes-active

Answer (score 1):

I won't use `RunInstances` as suggested on the accepted answer, because it means that the instance is being created, not ready to accept scripts. Check [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html#instance-launch)

Instead, use the [running state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#ec2_event_type)

```
{
  "detail": {
    "state": ["running"]
  },
  "detail-type": ["EC2 Instance State-change Notification"],
  "source": ["aws.ec2"]
}
```

Check also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51410672/will-an-amazon-ec2-instance-state-change-notification-be-triggered-when-an-insta) and [this one](https://repost.aws/questions/QUtiSghimtQoGL1R2qYyIEuw/eventbridge-troubleshooting).