# Catch event when an SSM-agent becomes active

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge, aws-ssm

I want to trigger a lambda whenever a new EC2 instance is registred in SSM's Fleet Manager (meaning the instance can be connected to using SSM), however I can't find what pattern to use in EventBridge.

Within EventBridge, I tried using the following pattern I found in the docs (so far its looks like the closest thing to my goal):

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ssm"],
  "detail-type": ["Inventory Resource State Change"]
}
```

However when I create a new EC2 and wait for its SSM agent to become active, it still doesn't trigger the above pattern.

Any idea how to catch this kind of event?

Comment: I couldn't find anything for that event in cloudtrail. I think you have to stream the SSM logs to Cloudwatch and create a notification system based on that